# GoogleCloudEngineで起動エラー

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine

GoogleCloudPlatformのVMインスタンスでCentOS7が入っています。
誤ってこ下記URLを参考に下記コードを実行し、rebootしたところ、SSH接続できなくなってしまいました。

備忘録）CentOS 7 で最初やってそうなことのまとめ。
不要サービスを停止
http://qiita.com/dumpty-alma@github/items/091862834317229559f1

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
rm '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/NetworkManager.service'
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service'    
rm '/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
```

Googleのシリアルコンソール出力はこちらです。今も連続的にこのような文字列が発生しています。

```
Sep 4 13:42:29 localhost accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying   to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable> Sep 4           
13:42:30 localhost google: Waiting for metadata server, attempt 18316 Sep 4   
13:42:30 localhost google: There is likely a problem with the network.
```

スナップショットを取り、新しくインスタンスを作成しましたが、起動できませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スタートアップスクリプトでchkconfigを起ち上げるようなものを入れ込むことで解決したりしませんか？
一応、スタートアップスクリプトは外部から渡せます。以下参照。
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: プロジェクトを削除したんですが、復帰できましたが、リンク先に書いてあることはよくわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManagerを止めるとnetworkの起動は従来通りchkconfig 経由になります。よって、`chkconfig network on`されていなければネットワークはたちあがりませんよ。